# Is Java fully object-oriented?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is java 100% object oriented ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974583/is-java-100-object-oriented)

Is Java a fully object-oriented language? If not, why? And which programming languages are fully object-oriented?