# How to check null element if it is integer array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, null, int

I'm quite new to Java and having an issue checking null element in integer array.
I'm using Eclipse for editor and the line that checks null element is showing error:

Line that complains:

```
if(a[i] != null) {
```

Error msg from Eclipse:

```
The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null
```

In PHP, this works without any problem but in Java it seems like I have to change the array type from integer to Object to make the line not complain (like below)

```
Object[] a = new Object[3];
```

So my question is if I still want to declare as integer array and still want to check null,
what is the syntax for it?

Code:

```
public void test() {
        int[] a = new int[3];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] != null) { //this line complains...
                System.out.println('null!');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Java, an `int` is a primitive type and cannot be `null`.  Objects, however, are stored as references, so if you declare an object reference but do not make a `new` object, the reference will be `null`.

`Integers` are object wrappers around `ints`, meaning they can be `null`.

```
public void test() {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[3];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] != null) { //should now compile
                System.out.println('null!');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know int and Integer are different.. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you do have `Integer[]` and just want to check whether or not there is are any `null` elements, `Arrays.asList(array).contains(null)`.

Comment: or better, the Common-Utils class ArrayUtils.IsEmpty()

Answer (score 8):

#### On primitive vs reference types

An `int` is a primitive type, which is distinct from a reference type. Only reference types can have the value `null`.

#### References

- [JLS 4.2 Primitive Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2)
- [JLS 4.3 Reference Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3)

#### Related questions

- [Is Java fully object-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054662/is-java-fully-object-oriented)
- [Is java 100% object oriented ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974583/is-java-100-object-oriented)

---

#### On `Integer` vs `int`

[`java.lang.Integer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is in fact a reference type, the designated "box" type for the primitive type `int`. Thus, an `Integer` variable can have the value `null`.

With the introduction of autoboxing in Java, conversions from `int` to `Integer` and vice versa can be done implicitly. But do keep in mind that they are very different types, and in fact an attempt to unbox `null` will throw `NullPointerException`.

#### References

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7)

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)
- [Why does autoboxing in Java allow me to have 3 possible values for a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923249/why-does-autoboxing-in-java-allow-me-to-have-3-possible-values-for-a-boolean)

---

#### On consequences of `Integer` being a reference type

One consequence is already mentioned: an `Integer` variable can have a `null` value. Another one is that the `==` operator on two `Integer` is a reference identity comparison, not numerical equality.

```
System.out.println(new Integer(0) == new Integer(0)); // prints "false"
```

Whenever possible, you should prefer primitive types to boxed types. Here's a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 49: Prefer primitive types to boxed primitives* (emphasis by author):

> In summary, use primitives in preference to boxed primitive whenever you have the choice. Primitive types are simpler and faster. If you must use boxed primitives, be careful! **Autoboxing reduces the verbosity, but not the danger, of using boxed primitives**. When your program compares two boxed primitives with the `==` operator, it does an identity comparison, which is almost certainly *not* what you want. When your program does mixed-type computations involving boxed and unboxed primitives, it does unboxing, and **when your program does unboxing, it can throw `NullPointerException`**. Finally, when your program boxes primitive values, it can result in costly and unnecessary object creations.

#### Related questions

- [Is it guaranteed that new Integer(i) == i in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831945/is-it-guaranteed-that-new-integeri-i-in-java)

  - Goes in detail about how `==` behaves for `Integer` and `int` operands

---

#### When `Integer` must be used

There is one glaring exception where `Integer` must be used over `int`: generics. Type parameters in Java generics must be reference types. So you can NOT have a [`List<int>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in Java; you must use a `List<Integer>` instead.

#### Related questions

- [Java noob: generics over objects only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015716/java-noob-generics-over-objects-only/)

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

---

#### On using the appropriate data structure

If you *must* have an `int[]` that permits `null` values, then the quick answer is to use `Integer[]`. Since you now have an array of reference types, some elements can be `null`. Be aware of all the consequences of working with reference types, or you may come across surprises.

At this point, however, I'd seriously consider using a `List<Integer>` instead (see *Effective Java 2nd Edition: Prefer lists to arrays*). Lists are much more feature-rich than arrays, and it interoperates well with the larger Java Collections Framework.

#### API references

- [`java.util.List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [Java Collections Framework Guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/)

Answer (score 4):

An 'int' cannot be null. An Integer (which is an object) can. So, as @Justin said, Integer[] will allow you to test for null, but if int[] is working for you, then you don't need to bother testing for null because it can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

int is a primitive type in java, and cannot be null. Only objects can be null.

Answer (score -1):

You can use arr[i] != '\0' like this. It worked for me.

```
public class IntNullCheck {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] intarr = new int[5];
    intarr[0] = 7;
    intarr[3] = 9;

    for(int n : intarr){
        if(n != '\0'){
            System.out.println(n);
        }else
            System.out.println("Null");
    }
}
}
```