# Comparing Numbers in Java

Tags: java, comparison, numbers

In Java, all numeric types extend from java.lang.Number. Would it be a good idea to have a method like the following:

```
public boolean areEqual(Number first, Number second) {
    if (first != null && second != null) {
        return first.equals(second);
    }
}
```

I'm concerned about cases where a double 2.00000 does not equal an int 2. Are these handled by the built-in equals? If not, is there any way to write a simple number compare function in java? (external libraries such as apache commons are ok)

Comment: Not to mention where a BigDecimal 2.000 does not equal a BigDecimal 2.0000..

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A `Double` is ***NEVER*** `equals` to an `Integer`. Moreover, a `double` is not the same as a `Double`.

Java has primitive types and reference types. The truly numeric types in Java do not extend from `Number`, because they're primitives.

You may want to consider a system where you're not mixing types, because that usually will cause a lot of trouble with implicit/explicit conversions that may/may not lose information, etc.

#### Related questions

On `int` vs `Integer`:

- [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)
- [Is Java fully object-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054662/is-java-fully-object-oriented)

On `Number` comparison:

- [Why doesn't `java.lang.Number` implement `Comparable`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable)
- [Comparing the values of two generic Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683202/comparing-the-values-of-two-generic-numbers)

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [JLS 4.2 4.2 Primitive Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2)

  > The *numeric types* are the integral types and the floating-point types. 
  >   The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long` and `char`.
  >   The floating-point types are `float` and `double`.

---

#### On mixed-type computation

Mixed-type computation is the subject of at least 4 puzzles in [*Java Puzzlers*](http://javapuzzlers.com/).

Here are various excerpts:

> it is generally best to avoid mixed-type computations [...] because they are inherently confusing [...] Nowhere is this more apparent than in conditional expressions. Mixed-type comparisons are always confusing because the system is forced to promote one operand to match the type of the other. The conversion is invisible and may not yield the results that you expect
>
> **Prescription**: Avoid computations that mix integral and floating-point types. Prefer integral arithmetic to floating-point.

Comment: I don't agree. All numbers are comparable. They come from math not Java. What would Pythagoras say to "Numbers are not comparable"? Sun and Oracle developers don't understand numbers correctly.

Comment: Numbers are comparable, that doesn't mean any systems representations of numbers are comparable.  You are mixing up the concept of number with a type called "Number"

Answer (score 18):

To compare two Numbers in Java you can use the `compareTo` from `BigDecimal`. BigDecimal can hold everything from short until double or BigInteger, so it's the perfect class for this.

So you can try to write something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Number n1, Number n2) {
    // ignoring null handling
    BigDecimal b1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(n1.doubleValue());
    BigDecimal b2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(n2.doubleValue());
    return b1.compareTo(b2);
}
```

This is surely not the best approach regarding to performance.
The following tests worked so far, at least with JDK7:

```
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Integer(2)) == -1);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Double(2.0)) == -1);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Double(Double.MAX_VALUE)) == -1);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Double(Double.MIN_VALUE)) == 1);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Double(1.000001)) == -1);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Double(1.000)) == 0);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new Double(0.25*4)) == 0);
assertTrue(compareTo(new Integer(1), new AtomicLong(1)) == 0);
```

Comment: For all `Number` implementations, prefer the `Type.valueOf(value)` to `new Type(value)`. They all provide caches, which will save memory in large scale applications.

Comment: I've just downvoted your answer because the conversion of Long.MAX_VALUE to a BigDecimal by using doubleValue() gives 9223372036854775808 instead of 9223372036854775807. It is even worse with the conversion from BigInteger to BigDecimal. Please follow pickypg's advise for correctness' sake, rather call BigDecimal.valueOf(long) and new BigDecimal(BigInteger) when converting integral numbers. 1647684687678982643434436666777443865 becomes 1647684687678982604257012050286346240 when applying your method on a number storable into a BigInteger.

Answer (score 6):

The specific method you suggest would fail, because it's using `equals()` inherited from `Object`.  That is, it would check to see if the `Number` *objects* were the same, not whether their *values* were the same.

<strike>If that was just an illustrative example, I will update my answer.</strike>

polygene's answer actually pretty much covers the ground I was heading for.  You may also be interested in this question: [Why doesn't java.lang.Number implement Comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable).

Comment: @polygenelubricants If I had to guess it's that the description of `equals` is inaccurate for all built-in Java implementations of `Number`. They all override `equals` to do an `instanceOf` check (and therefore a `null` check) and then check the raw value rather than doing a reference check, which is what is described. In other words, they _do_ check their `Class` _and_ value.

Comment: Correct.  Any Java object whose equals() method does reference comparison is in violation of the equals() contract.  You are always supposed to override equals and implement it correctly.  People just don't because they're lazy.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know whether the object references are the same, then the existing methods fit the bill.  A `Double` representing `2.0` and an `Integer` representing `2` are definitely different objects, and certainly not interchangeable in a general sense.

If you just want to know whether the numeric values are the same, you can use the [Number.doubleValue()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue()) method to convert both numbers to doubles, then compare those numbers together (probably allowing for a small tolerance, as most numbers are represented inexactly, such as 1.99999999996583 for what should be 2, depending on the intermediate calculation steps).  Something like the following:

```
private static final double EPSILON = 0.000000000000001d;    

public static boolean areEquivalentNumbers(Number a, Number b)
{
   if (a == null)
   {
      return b == null;
   }
   else if (b == null)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return Math.abs(a.doubleValue() - b.doubleValue()) < EPSILON;
   }
}
```

Comment: Quibble: any correctly implemented equals() method compares data, not references.

Comment: Since I often don't even know whether I'm getting strings, integers, or decimals, Andrzej's answer is *great*.  In fact, I also have:

public static boolean areEquivalentNumbers(String a, String b) {
  return areEquivalentNumbers(Double.parseDouble(a), Double.parseDouble(b));
 }

Comment: Epsilon? What happened to delta? Are we just throwing terms?

Answer (score 2):

On a tangent to a couple of the responses, may I suggest that instead of writing something like:

```
boolean compare(Object o1, Object o2)
{
  if (o1==null)
    return o2==null;
  if (o2==null)
    return false;
  return o1.equals(o2);
}
```

It's much more concise, and I believe slightly more efficient, to write:

```
boolean compare(Object o1, Object o2)
{
  return o1==o2 || o1!=null && o2!=null && o1.equals(o2);
}
```

If both are null, o1==o2 will return true. If they're not but they're the same object, that's fine too.

Technically the o2!=null is not necessary for most implementations of equals, but if you were really being so generic as to do this on Objects as in the above example, you of course wouldn't know how every override was written.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static boolean compareTo(Number d1, Number d2) {
    Double num1=d1.doubleValue();
    Double num2=d2.doubleValue();
     if(Double.compare(num1, num2)==0)
         return true;
     else
         return false;

}

OR
    public static boolean compareTo(Number d1, Number d2) {
     if(d1.doubleValue()==d2.doubleValue())
         return true;
     else
         return false;

}
```

Comment: .Above solution is already given by Lian in the previous post. Please not copy other's answer

Answer (score 0):

Comparing numbers between integer and floating point is almost never going to yield what you are after. If however this is a simple exercise, you could implement the comparison by comparing the string representations of the values, as in:

```
public boolean areEqual(Number first, Number second) {
    if (first == null) {
        return second == null;
    }
    if (second == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return first.toString().equals(second.toString());
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach!  Probably not great for large numbers of comparisons though, due to `String` operation inefficiency.

Comment: Doesn't work. ((Number)0.0f).toString().equals(((Number)0).toString())
===> false

Answer (score -1):

you cannot call

```
number.equals(number2);
```

because, if number is a Double and number2 is an Integer, they will not be of the same class and you will get an exception telling you of that fact.

You could write a comparison class yourself that accepts Number objects, but you will have to take into account the different subclasses of Number

Comment: `System.out.println(new Double(0).equals(new Long(0)));` prints `false`; it doesn't throw any `Exception`.