# assert equals int long float

Tags: java, junit

Is there an elegant way to assert numbers are equal while ignoring their classes? I want to use it in JUnit tests framework but for example

```
Assert.assertEquals(1,1L)
```

fails with java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.Integer<1> but was: java.lang.Long<1>

I expect there is a nice method somewhere which compares only value and works with int, long, float, byte, double, BigDecimal, BigInteger, you name it...

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: I agree. Have an upvote! I also think the answer is not trivial.

Comment: I was thinking about Number.toString.equals, but there is scientific format to deal with

Comment: For primitives, you can create overloads `assertEquals(int, int)`, `assertEquals(long, long)`, `assertEquals(float, float)` etc, which all call `Assert.assertEquals(a, b)`, and overload resolution will pick the appropriate one. You might well get ambiguous overload problems in some cases. I think that doing it for `Big*` against primitives might get trickier though. I'd question exactly why you really want this - how frequently are the operands of different types?

Comment: use `assertEquals("1",String.valueOf(1l))`

Comment: You could wrap your values in `BigDecimal`s.

Comment: If I run that piece of code, it just works fine... (Java 8, Junit 4.11)  maybe `Assert.assertThat(1, is(1L));` might also help you... You may need to implement your own `Matcher` then...

Comment: Convert to string on both sides, using the `Float.toString()` , and compare them.

Comment: I was also going to suggest to use *assertThat* here.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned the importance of epsilon for comparing  numbers in floating point representation.  I have added that in my answer below -- my answer also can handle both primitive and object, and integer and floating representation.  See if you like it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One workaround with some overhead would be to wrap the values in [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) objects, as `BigDecimal` constructor overloads take `long`, `int` and `double` primitives.

Since `new BigDecimal(1l).equals(new BigDecimal(1.0))` holds `true`,

```
Assert.assertEquals(new BigDecimal(1.0), new BigDecimal(1l));
```

should work for you.

**Edit**

As [Hulk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2513200/hulk) states below, the scale of the `BigDecimal` objects is used in the `equals` comparison, but not in the `compareTo` comparison. 
While the scale is set to a default `0` for the constructor taking `long`, it is inferred through some calculation in the constructor taking `double`. 
Therefore the safest way to compare values (i.e. in edge cases for `double` values) *might* be through invoking `compareTo` and checking the outcome is `0` instead.

Comment: I accept this because it is elegant one line solution

Comment: @PavelNiedoba cheers. Watch out about the overhead though, you **are** creating objects everytime.

Comment: Obligatory caution when using `equals` to compare `BigDecimals`: It is inconsistent with `compareTo` in that it also takes scale into account, [JavaDocs of BigDecimal.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6787142

Comment: @Hulk good point. Maybe comparing `doubleValue` from the `BigDecimal`s instead might be less error prone? I see that the scale is calculated, at least in the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor, so I'm wondering whether it might differ indeed at times when initializing as above...

Comment: @Hulk or otherwise just use `compareTo` I guess, no need to make things harder :)

Comment: @Hulk edited my answer. Thanks for the caveat, learned something today :)

Comment: I'm aware about the overhead, but this is for testing mainly so not an issue. I was aware about scale, but I would miss this too.  Cases like 1f/3 == 1d/3 are out of scope for this question, double value might be solution too.

Answer (score 10):

According to my reading of the JLS, the overload resolution for

```
Assert.assertEquals(1,1L)
```

should resolve to

```
Assert.assertEquals(long, long)
```

In short, the code snippet in the question is not a valid example of your actual problem.

(For the record, `assertEquals(long, long)`, `assertEquals(float, float)` and `assertEquals(double, double)` are *applicable by strict invocation*, and the first one is the most specific; see [JLS 15.12.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2).  The strict invocation context allows primitive widening, but not boxing or unboxing.)

If (as the evidence suggests) your call is resolving to `Assert.assertEquals(Object, Object)`, that implies that one of the operands must *already* be a boxed type.  The problem with that overload is that it is using the `equals(Object)` method to compare objects, and the contract for that method *specifies* that the result is `false` if the objects' respective types are different.

If that is what is going on in your real code, then I doubt that the suggestion of using the `is(T)` `Matcher` will work either.  The `is(T)` matcher is equivalent to `is(equalTo(T))` and the latter relies on `equals(Object)` ...

Is there an existing "nice method"?

AFAIK, no.

I think that the real solution is to be a bit more attentive to the types; e.g.

```
 int i = 1;
 Long l = 1L;
 Assert.assertEquals(i, l);         // Fails
 Assert.assertEquals((long) i, l);  // OK - assertEquals(Object, Object)
 Assert.assertEquals((Long) i, l);  // OK - assertEquals(Object, Object)
 Assert.assertEquals(i, (int) l);   // OK - assertEquals(long, long) 
                                    //      it would bind to an (int, int) 
                                    //      overload ... it it existed.   
 Assert.assertEquals(i, (long) l);  // OK - assertEquals(long, long)
```

Writing a custom `Matcher` would work too.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap that functionality in your own [Matcher](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Matchers-and-assertthat) and use it with `assertThat`.

Sample matcher:

```
class IsAnyNumber extends BaseMatcher {
  final Object expected;
  //...
  public boolean matches(Object actual) {
    // compare / transform / check type / ensure: String, double, int, long
    // example via BigDecimal as seen from Mena (without checks)
    return new BigDecimal(expected).equals(new BigDecimal(actual));
  }
  // ...
}

// somewhere else:
public static IsAnyNumber is(Object expected) {
  return new IsAnyNumber(expected);
}
```

In your tests you then call that static method:

```
assertThat(1, is(1L));
assertThat(1, is(1.0));
assertThat(1L, is(1));
```

This way you can reuse your matcher and the assert statement is more readable in the end.

Disclaimer: this is only pseudo-code and was not yet tested, but should work with some tweaking.

But beware also from [Comparing Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214448/comparing-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own assert methods and compare the double values for the primitives. If a `BigDecimal` is used, the primitive value has to be converted to a `BigDecimal`

```
static void assertEquals(Number number1, Number number2) {
  Assert.assertEquals(number1.doubleValue(), number2.doubleValue());
}

static void assertEquals(BigDecimal number1, BigDecimal number2) {
  if (number2.compareTo(number1) != 0) {
    Assert.fail("Values are not equal. ..... ");
  }
}

static void assertEquals(Number number1, BigDecimal number2) {
  assertEquals(new BigDecimal(number1.doubleValue()), number2);
}

static void assertEquals(BigDecimal number1, Number number2) {
  assertEquals(number2, number1);
}
```

It can be used this way:

```
assertEquals(1, new BigDecimal("1.0"));
assertEquals(1.0d, 1);
assertEquals(new Float(1.0f), 1.0d);
assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1.00000"), new BigDecimal("1.0"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to accept all eight types of numerical values (primitive and object), the method has to take string arguments.  The caller will have to remember to cast the value to string by this idiom:

```
""+value
```

Also, in case the value is not an integer (`int`, `Integer`, `long`, `Long`) but a floating point representation (`float`, `double`, `Float`, `Double`), the method must also take a argument `epsilon` to tolerate imprecision due to the representation.

So here is an implementation idea (for now I ignore the cases of NaN and positive and negative zeros of double -- these can be added if a truly solid implementation is needed)

```
private static boolean equalsNumerically(String n1String
                                        , String n2String
                                        , double epsilon) {
    try {
        Long n1Long = new Long(n1String);
        Long n2Long = new Long(n2String);
        return n1Long.equals(n2Long);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        /*
         * If either one of the number is not an integer, try comparing
         * the two as Double
         */
        try {
            Double n1Double = new Double(n1String);
            Double n2Double = new Double(n2String);
            double delta = ( n1Double - n2Double) / n2Double;
            if (delta<epsilon) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

**Testing code**

```
    int     primitiveInt = 1;
    long    primitiveLong = 1L;
    float   primitiveFloat = 0.999999F;
    double  primitiveDouble = 0.999999D;
    Integer objectInt = new Integer(1);
    Long    objectLong = new Long(1);
    Float   objectFloat = new Float(0.999999);
    Double  objectDouble = new Double(0.999999);

    final double epsilon = 1E-3;

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveLong, 0)); 
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+primitiveLong, 0): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, primitiveLong, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveLong, epsilon));
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+primitiveLong, epsilon)): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, primitiveLong, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveFloat, epsilon)); 
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+primitiveFloat, 0): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, primitiveFloat, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveDouble, epsilon)); 
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+primitiveDouble, epsilon): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, primitiveDouble, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectInt, 0)); 
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+objectInt, 0): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, objectInt, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectLong, 0)); 
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+objectLong"
            + ", \"\"+objectLong, 0): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, primitiveLong, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectFloat, epsilon));
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+objectFloat, epsilon)): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, objectFloat, epsilon);

    Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectDouble, epsilon)); 
    System.out.format("Test passed: "
            + "Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(\"\"+primitiveInt"
            + ", \"\"+objectDouble, 0): %s %s %s%n"
            , primitiveInt, objectDouble, epsilon);
```

**Test output**

```
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveLong, 0): 1 1 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveLong, epsilon)): 1 1 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveFloat, 0): 1 0.999999 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+primitiveDouble, epsilon): 1 0.999999 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectInt, 0): 1 1 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectLong, 0): 1 1 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectFloat, epsilon)): 1 0.999999 0.001
Test passed: Assert.assertTrue(equalsNumerically(""+primitiveInt, ""+objectDouble, 0): 1 0.999999 0.001
```

Comment: Better to use `String.valueOf(value)` then `""+value`. Because it is cleaner and more understandable.