# Java generics method fails on number comparison

Tags: java, generics

See the tiny method below. The `boo1 = ...` line goes fine, probably as it does object ID comparison. The second `boo2 = ...` line gives a compile error "Operator `>` cannot be applied to T,T". I don't understand why. After all `T extends Number` (as you can see in the method signature), so comparisons like `>` should be possible. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static <T extends Number> int[] where(T[] arr, T val) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) return null;

        boolean boo1 = arr[0] == val; //Compiles happily, as does "!="
        boolean boo2 = arr[0] > val;  //Doesn't compile (nor does ">=", "<", "<="

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You're assuming that the relational operators support `Number` operands; they don't.

Comment: maybe help [Comparing Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111857/1518100)

Comment: `arr[0] == val` compiles and checks whether the two references are references to *the same object*. It probably is not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're assuming that the relational operators support `Number` operands; they don't. Only `Number`s that box primitive types (e.g. `Integer`, `Long`) do; others such as `BigInteger` don't.

You can add an additional bound to `T` to require it to be `Comparable`:

```
<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
```

And you can pass in any types that are both `Number`s *and* are `Comparable`: this includes `Integer`, `Long`, `BigInteger` etc.

Then you can use:

```
arr[0].compareTo(val) > 0
```

(but you might care to watch out for nulls).

Also, you shouldn't be using `==` and `!=` to check for equality/inequality: use `equals` instead:

```
arr[0].equals(val)  // Instead of ==
!arr[0].equals(val) // Instead of !=
```

You can, alternatively, use `arr[0].compareTo(val) ==/!= 0`. That may be better, in fact, because e.g. `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` have equals methods that consider scale, so `[1.00].equals([1.0])` is false, whereas `[1.00].compareTo([1.0]) == 0` is true. Ultimately, it depends on what you're trying to achieve as to which way to choose.

Comment: Even for those that box primitive types, you're running up against autoboxing. Comparing `Integer` with `>` is illegal. It's just that Java is clever in that case and replaces it with the result of `Integer.intValue`. But that's a trick of the Java compiler, akin to syntax sugar.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo there's no difference in "legality" or "cleverness" between comparing an `Integer` with an `Integer`, an `int` with an `int` or a `double` with an `int`: in all cases, [the operands undergo binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1).

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way:

```
public static <T extends Number> int[] where(T[] arr, T val) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) return null;

    boolean boo1 = arr[0] == val; //Compiles happily, as does "!="
    boolean boo2 = arr[0].intValue() > val.intValue();
    // Or doubleValue()

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `intValue()` doesn't work for e.g. `arr[0] == 1.2` and `val == 1.1`. `doubleValue()` doesn't work for `Long`s/`BigInteger`s etc that are too big.

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui the result is an `int[]`; the parameters aren't, and it's parameters that are being compared.

Comment: There are many other cases that will not work either. All of `Long`, `Float`, `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` can hold numbers outside the `int` range, from which you would not get the expected result.