# Every java program is Object Oriented

Tags: java, oop

Our Java instructor always asks us to prove that "Every java program is Object Oriented"

How would I go about proving this is true?

Comment: You can misuse Java to do procedure oriented coding like C. :)

Comment: Tell him to prove "Every CS Professor is competent"

Comment: zzz.... you should switch your instructor.

Comment: It depends on your instructor's definition of *object oriented*, basically. All Java programs are using some objects (at least the `String[]` given to the main method), but I'm not sure we can name this already object oriented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you cannot have a main that isn't part of a class. Hence a class must exist in order to have a valid program.

But that's really nit-picking since you don't actually have to *instantiate* that class to do something. You can write a complete program with just static methods that instantiate no objects at all.

Whether it's a *useful* program without using objects like `System.out` is another matter.

Some OO purists will argue that Java isn't *pure* OO and they're probably right (in my opinion). That doesn't make it any less useful.

Comment: You'll have still at least one object, namely the String[] given to the main method :-p

Answer (score 2):

See here.This defines the reason why Java is object oriented programming language.

- [Is Java 100% object oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974583/is-java-100-object-oriented)

Answer (score -1):

Every java program is not Object oriented due to the presence of primitives and statics.