# what makes java not pure object oriented language?

Tags: java

I think java is pure object oriented, but in real it is not. But i dont know why java is not pure object oriented language, please help me to find out the reason.

Comment: What is your definition of pure object oriented? And why do you think Java is not? Any references?

Comment: Have a look at a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974583/is-java-100-object-oriented

Comment: And this is your second question that will be closed. You should think about it.

Comment: I support the close because it has been asked quite often at SO - but not the reason: it is a very real question. Please, close voters, take your time to find the duplicates, this helps the OP better then having a question downvoted and closed like this.

Comment: Hence OOP language always deals with only objects that is, every thing should be object whereas in java we use primitive data type(int, float ) that are not objects, so java in not pure OOP but more OOP supported than C language. Hence concept of wrapper classed (Integer etc)has been introduced in Java to resolve these non-object data type.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a homework question, right?

Primitive types, that's why. For instance try this:

```
int i = 42;
System.err.println(i.toString());
```

Comment: +1 because you gave an example

Comment: Struggling to understand the significance of "This is a homework question, right?"

Answer (score 3):

The usual objection is that Java is not "purely" OO because it has primitive types (int, double, etc.), which are not objects.

Answer (score 1):

To make proof by contradiction: Java has `int`, and `int`, like all primitive types in Java, is not an `Object`. There are possibly more reasons, though.