# Java is pure object oriented or not?

Tags: java

I'd like to know if Java is pure object oriented or not. Please explain it with example. I have goggled it, but I couldn't find the exact answer.

Comment: You'd have to define the term "pure object oriented" in order to make the question answerable.

Comment: I would really like to see an example of *pure object oriented programming language*.

Comment: Do you mean an *object based programming language* or an *object oriented programming language*? Because the prefix "pure" does not make any sense for the latter...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974583/is-java-100-object-oriented?rq=1 ... summary: can't be answered without a good definition of what "pure object oriented" even means.

Comment: Whether it is or isn't, when is this ever relevant?

Comment: @Thor84no For instance in an exam. :P

Comment: Brother , IDEAL cases are just theoretical. IDEAL gas equation, ideal ohms law, and IDEAL OOPS. Java is Realistic OOPS.. :) :D

Comment: Also: see [this programming.SE question for an attempt at defining "pure OO"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/formal-definition-for-term-pure-oo-language).

Comment: @brimborium I rest my case. :P

Comment: Although java has primitive types, you can implement them as object. I think there is no language out there that is 100% object oriented...

Comment: For comparison, the Smalltalk programming language basically has only two things: objects, and messages that are sent to objects. Essentially everything else is implemented by sending messages to objects. It has *no* "primitive" (non-object) types (nor any ability to operate on them). It doesn't even have things like if/then/else or loops built into the language--those are implemented as objects and messages. Even simple things like addition and subtraction are done by sending messages to objects. Compared to that, Java really isn't even particularly close to pure object orientation.

Comment: Yes Java is purely object-oriented, please read the complete explanation https://programmingmitra.blogspot.com/2016/06/why-java-is-purely-object-oriented-or-why-not.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are lot of arguments around whether Java is purely object oriented or not.
Java should be considered as purely object oriented language as it has wrapper classes.
So you can use `Integer`, `Float` etc. instead of `int`, `float` etc. (there are a total of eight primitive types).

But since Java has those eight primitive types, the critics will say Java is not purely object-oriented.

Comment: -1. Can somebuddy correct me please??

Comment: What is "pure" object oriented? Can you explain? And even if it has wrappers, it still has types that are not objects which you can use with no problems.

Comment: yes i can correct you. yes java has wrappers. but it has primitives as well. dont say.. that now java has wrappers.. so we can express integer,float etc as objects so java is now pure oo.  thing is , yes wrappers are there.. but we can stil have int, float as primitives. so java is not purely object oriented.  refer to update to my answer below. java isnt pure oo #fact.. if u feel otherwise , thats another story.

Comment: @Mukul Goel - You are seeing in from one side(primitive type) only. Will you not consider a java program pure-OO which uses Wrapper objects(Integer, Float etc) instead of int and float???

Comment: @ArunKumar : yes I would consider that program a pure OO. But that is just one of the case and java allows us to use the primitives. Thus Java, as a language is not pure OO.

Comment: So you're basically saying that "according to [you]" Java is one thing, and according to everybody else it is another. So what is the point of this answer?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition  : In a world of `supporters/advocates` and `criticits`, you can consider me in supporters / advocate club who think Java is Pure OO Language.

Comment: Well, you're wrong.

Answer (score 15):

For example it contains 8 primitive data types.
For a language to be "*pure oo*" everything should exists as objects, but `int`, `float`, `char`, .. etc are not objects in Java.

Here's an example:

```
int i = 42;
System.err.println(i.toString());
```

Comment: @MIkul Goel but java have wrapper classes for these data types primitives which convert thise into objects .....

Comment: Yes but also supports primitives while pure OO language doesn't

Comment: Yes, some would say we have wrappers. BUT we can use the primitive datatypes without the wrappers(i.e. not as objects).. OO says..everything should be treated as objects.. SO .. NO pure OO.. :-)

Comment: And what is the difference between a primitive type and a type without the function member toString or any other function member? For example, in C++, a object is "a region of storage". So, under this definition, an interger is an object. What is the (unambiguous) definition of object?

Comment: @Peregring-lk : How about.. instance of a Class?

Comment: @MukulGoel Good point, but I think if a primitive type is an instance of a class or not, is transparent for you. So, I don't see any difference from a programmer's point of view. I come from the C++ world, and an instance of a class with implicitly default constructor, implicitly copy and move constructors/assignment operators (a POD class), and POD subobjects, has no differences with primitive types from a point of view of performance, except for the fact this class is a compoud type (it requieres more storage and time to reserve that storage).

Answer (score 9):

Java is a OOP language and it is not a pure Object Based Programming Language.
Many languages are Object Oriented. There are seven qualities to be satisfied for a programming language to be pure Object Oriented. They are:

- Encapsulation/Data Hiding
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism
- Abstraction
- All predefined types are objects
- All operations are performed by sending messages to objects
- All user defined types are objects.

Java is not because it supports Primitive datatype such as int, byte, long... etc, to be used, which are not objects.
Contrast with a pure OOP language like Smalltalk, where there are no primitive types, and boolean, int and methods are all objects.

This answer is taken from http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_Java_not_a_pure_OOP_Language

Comment: That's not a trustable reference and does not cite its references either. Those 7 qualities, who says so?

Comment: actually its not at all  true ans.

Answer (score 6):

no it has primitive data types, thus i would say its not completely object oriented.
i think [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) can be considered *pure* object oriented than java.

**Straight from wiki**
 `Smalltalk is a "pure" object-oriented programming language, meaning that, unlike Java and C++, there is no difference between values which are objects and values which are primitive types. In Smalltalk, primitive values such as integers, booleans and characters are also objects`

Comment: Sorry, but more/less/pure object oriented makes no sense.

Comment: yes, it does not. i meant small talk is pure object oriented than java\

Comment: Still makes no sense. How do you measure *object-orientedness*?

Comment: @m0skit0 did you check my quoted text from wiki ?? .. i am no OOP guru, nor i know smalltalk. :P

Comment: That's why in Wikipedia they put **"pure"** (between quotes)... because you can't measure such thing, and as such, you cannot say if a language is more/less pure object oriented than another one. And anyway, what does "pure object oriented" mean?

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for the info, tbh, i never really came across this question before. the only thing i understand from the wiki is in smalltalk which is considered as "pure"OO language there is no place for primitive which java supports, again you can say that java has wrappers which can be used in place of primitives. i think you are right, measuring "pure"OO" is kinda stupid .. :P

Comment: And what is the definition of "object" in your quote?