# Are Java's primitives first class citizens?

Tags: java, oop

In [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://MITPress.MIT.Edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#call_footnote_Temp_121) by Gerald Jay Sussman and Harry Abelson first-class citizens are described with:

- They may be named by variables.
- They may be passed as arguments to procedures.
- They may be returned as the results of procedures.
- They may be included in data structures.

For me it means that primitive data type is the first-class citizen. However is some [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974624/2047418) I see answer considering primitives as non first-class citizens.

The question is: are Java's primitives first class citizen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*By the definition in your question*, yes, they are. The definition being used by others may not be the same as the definition in your question. If you use a different definition, then they may not meet it. For instance, in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974624/2047418) you linked, the definition implied by the question would involve their being derived from `Object`, which of course they aren't, and so by **that** definition, they aren't.

It all comes down to what you mean by "first-class citizen."

Comment: You're saying basically anything can be a first class citizen, as long as you define "first class citizen" that way. First class citizens must support all operations *generally available* to other entities. Primitives can't be used as a type argument for generics, so I feel in a general sense, they aren't first class citizens (which although may see like a broad definition, isn't as broad as you're actually making it)

Comment: @VinceEmigh: If it were *me*, I would just stay away from the entire term, I don't think it's useful. That said, to me the definition you're implying would be a better fit for how I think of it than the one in the OP's question. There's no question that there are things you can do with classes that you can't do with primitives, so...